# Inserting JSON file in Meteor

Tags: json, mongodb, coffeescript, meteor

I have a form and I need to put the data of that form in collection, using coffeescript
I am currently doing these in my client coffeescript file:

```
@Question = new Meteor.Collection('questions')
Template.question.events
  'submit #question-form' : (event) ->
    QuestionData = $('#question-form').serializeJSON()
    Question. insert QuestionData
```

I am not sure whether these data is being inserted or not. Please give me some useful ideas

Thank You in advance !!!

Comment: Check it in the console?

Comment: @HubertOG How to check it from console ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools you can use:

1)  You can add a line to javascript:

`debugger`

your client browser will stop when it reaches that line.  Sometimes you have to be in an inspect element screen already before it triggers.  I do this often in Chrome and Firefox.  Firefox has a debugger tab; chrome, a sources tab.

2) You can use mini-mongo in the client to check for the new record.  In the console (you can get to the console as a tab as described above) type

`Question.find().fetch()`

You can also write

`id = Question.insert QuestionData`

`console.log 'Question.findOne("' + id + '")`
which should give an easy to copy and paste.

Comment: Question.find().fetch() in console show "[]" is this what we get ?? or there is error in inserting the json object in collection ??

Comment: That is an empty array, so it did not go in.  I suspect you need to define the @Question collection in your server code as well.          For help formatting mongo calls, use the console to test the syntax if you don't get the code right.  Just remember to add .fetch(), and to write JS not Coffee

Comment: I have define @Question in server side too...from console when I insert the object, it is inserted.FOr example in console:
Question.insert({name:"rohan"});
"KACRczBmWBzgKj7ij"
Question.find().fetch()
[]

Comment: ..oh I got it. I put the syntax at my coffeescript and it is working fine. Thank you so very  much..!!! :)

Comment: The third comment down made me want to comment that on the server you have to give things permission, once you have turned autopublish off.  So when that happens to me, it is because I made a record that does not match my own tests of what the server will allow the client to see.

Answer (score 0):

In a separate terminal/dos prompt fire up the mongo console using.

`meteor mongo`

then to list all the questions in the mongo console type

`db.questions.find().pretty()`